# Ext JS 4.1 - Failed to load svg.sencha.io error after trying to save chart

Tags: extjs4, extjs, extjs4.1

I'm getting **"Failed to load http://svg.sencha.io/"** error while trying to **export my chart**:

```
chart.save({
    type: 'image/png'
});
```

Any ideas how can I handle this exception?

Comment: It would suggest that you cannot make an http connection to the address specified. We actually amended the source code in our application to redirect the chart svg to our local server side svg handler to produce an image output.